I cannot find a way to fix my Reverb/WebSocket. It's not working
I cannot find where I went wrong in my code to get my Reverb/WebSocket working.
I have tried setting a new port for this, but it's still not working. I looked at another person's code where it works, but I can't find where my error is.
my code is here github
edit:
I can connect inside my Docker container.
I using Sail if this help
Here is my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
laravel.test:
    build:
        context: './vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.4'
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args:
            WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
    image: 'sail-8.4/app'
    extra_hosts:
        - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    ports:
        - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
    environment:
        WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
        LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
    volumes:
        - '.:/var/www/html'
    networks:
        - sail
    depends_on:
        - mysql
        - redis
        - mailpit
mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
        - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test:
            - CMD
            - mysqladmin
            - ping
            - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
phpmyadmin:
    image: 'phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin'
    ports:
        - '9080:80'
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    networks:
        - sail
redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
    volumes:
        - 'sail-redis:/data'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test:
            - CMD
            - redis-cli
            - ping
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
mailpit:
    image: 'axllent/mailpit:latest'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_PORT:-1025}:1025'
        - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
    networks:
        - sail

networks:
sail:
driver: bridge
volumes:
sail-mysql:
driver: local
sail-redis:
driver: local

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

hav to add this  "- '${REVERB_SERVER_PORT:-8080}:8080'" to my ports: under  laravel.test
